Why vite is sending duplicate javascript files to client?
In the nuxt-bridge project, i have just installed and enabled vite. After i run build command, and run the server, i see duplicate javascript files on browser network tab. One is added with link tag with prefect attr to html and  Other one is imported via entry-legacy javascript file. Is it expected behaviour? If not, how can i disable the one imported from entry-legacy javacript file?

As it shown in the image, after enabling vite in the project i started to see two the same file in network tab.
I have tried to change legacy plugin but it is not it. It looks like this now:


export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    legacy({
      targets: ['defaults', 'not IE 11'],
      renderLegacyChunks: false,
    }),
  ],
});



Any idea why?
